# I added keys to the list elements, but it still sends me the warning about unique keys

Tags: javascript, react-native

I added the keys like that:

```
export const Field = ({ state, onCellPress }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.field}>
      { state?.map((row, rowIndex) => (
        <View style={styles.row} key={`${rowIndex}`}>
          { row?.map((value, columnIndex) => (
            <Cell
              text={value}
              onPress={onCellPress}
              row={rowIndex}
              column={columnIndex}
              key={`${columnIndex}`}
            />
          ))}
        </View>
      ))}
    </View>
  );
}
```

But I still get the warning "Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
I tried also like that:

```
    <Cell
      text={value}
      onPress={onCellPress}
      row={rowIndex}
      column={columnIndex}
      key={`${rowIndex}:${columnIndex}`}
    />
```

But I still get it. What do I do wrong?

Comment: easiest way to get ride of that error is to install uuid package and use it to identify each child

Answer (score 1):

Here you need to work on couple of things:-

1. Check if you are iterating this component from parent, if yes pass a key to the outer-most element also.
2. Are you going to manipulate the array such as re-order, filtering, etc. If so you need to rethink about uniques key as it may lead to bugs in future.
3. If required pass a key to element inside the children as well

For reference i am attaching two links here:
[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28329550/8355854)
[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43892905/8355854)

Comment: 1. This component isn't element of an outer list, if I understand you correctly

Comment: 2. The elements will not be reordered, that's why I think that it's ok to use indexes as keys

Comment: 3. Inside the child (Cell component) there is no list

Comment: Maybe I didn't get your idea

Comment: @OlgaClimova could you please key as key={`${rowIndex}:${columnIndex}:${value}`} for Cell component, if possible add a key property to outermost View component as well